# Running Jade on Windows runs CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, pug, npm

I installed the jade compiler using `npm install -g jade`.
However, when I try to run Jade from the command line, it mysteriously runs CoffeeScript.

```
PS C:\Users\P> get-command jade

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
-----------     ----                                               ----------
Application     jade.cmd


PS C:\Users\P> jade
coffee>
(^C again to quit)
coffee>

PS C:\Users\P> jade --version
CoffeeScript version 1.6.2
PS C:\Users\P> cd .\AppData\Roaming\npm
PS C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm> cat .\jade.cmd
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\jade\bin\jade" %*
) ELSE (
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\jade\bin\jade" %*
)
PS C:\Users\P\AppData\Roaming\npm>
```

Why is this happening??

**Update**
ok i did a 'where' jade.cmd and apparently there was another .cmd file which was calling coffeescript instead of jade.

Comment: What happens when you run simply node in REPL mode.

Comment: that works without any problems http://screencast.com/t/YL9DG7RnzffV

Comment: Hey @pdeva - finding the second jade.cmd file - does that mean your problem? if so - I think that should be an answer. I know another poster told you it wasn't the case... but if you've got a solution - then you were right the first time in putting it as an answer. Just make it clear that it solved your problem in the answer - if you do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i did a 'where' jade.cmd and apparently there was another .cmd file which was calling coffeescript instead of jade.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @Shadowfax he found the answer -- second jade.cmd file